# Cancel a PayPal order through API

Tags: paypal

I have as shopping cart which uses PayPal Website Payments Standard,becasue of some reason i want to cancel a order in the paypal using Apis available in Paypal.
How can approach this?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "cancel an order" do you mean you want to refund the payment?  If so, you can do this using the [RefundTransaction API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/refundtransaction-api-operation-nvp), or if you're using [Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro), the [Refund API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/pay-api-operation).